# Node-gyp rebuild Error

Tags: node.js, npm-install

[image]
while trying to install node dependency(npm install) error Am using node version v4.4.0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an older version of npm.  You might want to get the latest by running `npm install npm`.

Contextify actually isn't needed since you're running Node version >4.  I suspect that you haven't explicitly included contextify but rather it is being included as a dependency by some other package.  Try to figure out what package that is and see if there's a newer version of it that.  See here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/785